# SetShareIntent from the mainactivity is never used locally.. What does it mean?

Tags: java, android, share

I have  developed simple image app that is suppose to swipe the images from left to right .After reading this link http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html#set-share-intent. I implemented the codes in my mainActivity.java. This code is suppose to show sharing option at the top along the actionbar. However, I am getting little yellow lamp near this code ..private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {...What does it mean.. Following is my mainActivity.java code..

```
   import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer oursong;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      oursong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
      oursong.start ();
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;



  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate menu resource file.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

      // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
      MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

      // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
      mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

      // Return true to display menu
      return true;
  }



     @Override
     protected void onPause(){
     super.onPause();
      oursong.release();
 }

}
```

Error problems

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
[Accessibility] Missing contentDescription attribute on image   fullimage.xml   /Grid View/res/layout   line 6  Android Lint Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
<uses-sdk> tag should specify a target API level (the highest verified version; when running on later versions, compatibility behaviors may be enabled) with android:targetSdkVersion="?"   AndroidManifest.xml /Copy of galleryDemo    line 7  Android Lint Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details.    AndroidManifest.xml /DailySounds    line 8  Android Lint Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Should explicitly set android:allowBackup to true or false (it's true by default, and that can have some security implications for the application's data)  AndroidManifest.xml /Copy of galleryDemo    line 10 Android Lint Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The value of the field MainActivity.mShareActionProvider is not used    MainActivity.java   /Copy of ViewpagerImageGallery/src/com/manishkpr/viewpagerimagegallery  line 29 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
This method has a constructor name  MainActivity.java   /SecondActivityApp/src/com/secondactivityapp    line 28 Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Use a layout_height of 0dp instead of wrap_content for better performance   fullimage.xml   /Grid View/res/layout   line 9  Android Lint Problem
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.manishkpr.viewpagerimagegallery.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It means that it is a private function and it has never been called within your activity. It is not an error. It is just saying that setShareIntent is useless because it has never been used

Comment: @hoomi... Should it remove the whole code starting from // Call to update to the end of the code ?

Comment: yes because the whole method has been never used locally. Unless you are doing some sort of reflection later on in your code, you can remove the method

Comment: @hoomi... now I seeing two yellow lamps near  private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider; AND  mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

Comment: That is because the only place that you were using it was inside setShareIntent method. since you deleted that method, the variables are not used anywhere else. Hence you are getting the yellow lamps. Anyways these are only warnings. Why are you so worries about these warnings?

Comment: @hoomi...Because whenever I try to run on my device it says "there is a problem parsing the package"

Comment: Can you have a look at the console? These yellow lamps are not causing the issue.

Comment: @hoomi...let me try exporting the project again because I am not able to see any thing on my console...

Comment: @hoomi still the same result..."there is a problem parsing the package"

Comment: Are you using eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: Have you opened the problems tab to see what the problem is?

Comment: can you please tell where is the problem tab in eclipse ?

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcprbview.htm

Comment: you mean logact error ? I am using eclipse Luna

Comment: Your problem is in compilation. Those types of error do not appear in LogCat. You can show the problem from the following menu Window > Show View > Other... > General > Problems.

Comment: ok.. got it... will paste the image in couple of minutes..

Comment: @hoomi.. Please see the Error part..

Comment: There is no major issue in there either. Do you see this error on the phone or on eclipse?

Comment: @hoomi ...on the device...I set my minsdk version to 8..Now I can see the images.. However, i am not able to see the share option at the top ...

Answer (score 0):

If there is only a "yellow lamp" icon beside that line, then it's just a warning. Your program will run smoothly regardless, but it simply states that the intent is not used anywhere in your program (it's placed there unnecessarily) so you should try removing that line. If your program still runs smoothly, you are done.

Comment: i am not able to run the app on my device it says "there is a problem parsing the package"

Comment: This because your app is not compatible with your device. It might happen when u set the minSDKVersion value to high and If your device API level is lower then minSDKVersion then it gives parsing package error or may be u have set the maxSDKVersion to lower than your device API level.

like for example  If your device is Android 2.1 & if u set the APK  minSDKVersion to 10 then it wont work in the Android 2.1 and will give the parsing package error.

Comment: @ Vaishakhi verma...Please see my manifest.xml file... I can see the images. But cannot see the share option at the top

Comment: may b u already know abt this but just in case u dont: One of the most Common fix to this problem is to Turn on “Allow installation of apps from unknown Sources”. To do so Follow the Below Simple steps
Go to your Device Setting Menu
Scroll down and Click on Applications
Now Check the Box of Unknown Sources to allow installation of non Market Applications
...if this does not solve ur error then try to transfer ur apk file to ur device once again ..it may hv got corrupted while sending ..just try it..